# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode', I use the sklearn inPython to do machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I don't know why the python 3 kernel told me 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

X_digits,y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y = True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_digits,y_digits,random_state=42)
y_train.shape
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
n_labeled = 50

log_reg = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
log_reg.fit(X_train[:n_labeled], y_train[:n_labeled])
log_reg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: pls provide correct code snippet :) you did not show, which variable you wanted decode

Comment: ’from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

X_digits,y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y = True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_digits,y_digits,random_state=42)‘
’y_train.shape‘
（1347，）
’from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
n_labeled = 50

log_reg = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
log_reg.fit(X_train[:n_labeled], y_train[:n_labeled])
log_reg.score(X_test, y_test)‘
the error is from log_reg.fit(X_train[:n_labeled], y_train[:n_labeled])
@DYZ,@y.y